# OUT OF MEMORY only when virtual limit is hit?

Tags: c++, c, memory-management, winapi

As I know in win32 every program receives say 4GB of virtual memory. Memory manager is responsible for offloading chunks of memory from physical memory to disk.

Does it imply that malloc or any other memory allocation API will throw OUT_OF_MEMORY exception only when virtual limit is hit?  I mean is it possible for malloc to fail even if program is far from its virtual size limit e.g. none of physical memory can be offloaded to disk. Assume disk have unlimited capacity and no specific limitation is set.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/06/08/out-of-memory-does-not-refer-to-physical-memory.aspx

Comment: "...By now it should be clear why “out of memory” errors usually have nothing to do with how much physical memory you have, or how even how much storage is available. It’s almost always about the address space, which on 32 bit Windows is relatively small and easily fragmented..."

So fragmentation it is.

Comment: Minor point: A malloc() failure will return NULL rather than throw an exception. new throws an exception. At least that is what it is required to do, the OS may well do something else, and indeed may do different things depending on the cause of the failure.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Remember that memory can be fragmented and that `malloc` won't be able to find a sufficiently large chunk to serve the size you requested. This can easily be way before you hit your 4 GiB limit.

Comment: Hi, memory fragmentation throws an OOM? It's a bit severe error for a not so uncommon situation...

Comment: When the allocater can't find enough (continous) memory, what else should it do?

Answer (score 6):

The virtual memory limit on Win 32 is 2Gb. On Win 64, it's much bigger.

`malloc` doesn't throw an exception - it returns NULL. NULL return, or exception, the memory manager can fail well before the 2Gb limit is reached if

- The paging file isn't big enough. If the paging file is limited either by policy, or by lack of room to expand: If memory allocations can't be met by page file availability then they will fail.
- Fragmentation. The underlying memory manager allocates memory in 4Kb chunks. Its quite possible, through patterns of allocations and deallocations to end up with a small amount of allocated memory, but a fragmented virtual memory meaning that there is no contiguous area large enough to meet a particular request.

Comment: On Win32 memory limit can be extended to 3.5 GB using a patch from Microsoft

Comment: Window's address space can be extended to 3Gb/process with a compile and boot time flag. 3.5Gb is typical usable memory limit for PCs that map the PCI bus onto the 4Gb address range of the CPU (without PAE)

Comment: Using the /3Gb switch is such a terribly bad idea I didn't think it worth mentioning. But was IS worth mentioning is, On windows 64, a 32 bit app CAN be given a full 4Gb address space (As long as its linked with the /largeaddressaware flag).

Answer (score 1):

For full chapter and verse on Windows virtual memory check out this post on Mark Russinovich's Blog (lots of other great stuff here too):

[Pushing the Limits of Windows: Virtual Memory](http://blogs.technet.com/markrussinovich/archive/2008/11/17/3155406.aspx)

If memory fragmentation is your problem and writing custom allocators isn't your thing you could consider enabling the low fragmentation heap:

[Low Fragmentation Heap (Windows)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366750%28VS.85%29.aspx)

This is on by default these days mind you.

Answer (score 0):

how about allocating a few smaller areas, if a huge one isn't available?

Comment: What good would that do?  If the program is asking for a large contiguous chunk of memory, it's presumably intending to use it as a large contiguous chunk of memory, and several smaller chunks would require extra computation built in to use like that.  In any case, a program that runs low on memory is likely to run out shortly, so extra measures to reclaim memory are likely wasted.

Comment: What good it would do? It might be possible to adapt the algorithm to work with several smaller chunks of memory. So it might result in a working program. Seems pretty fair to me.